# how to redirect folder and its subfolders to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i have a wordpress blog and i have changed my "uploads" folder to subdomain.
My previous address was like this.
https://guilaneman.ir/`wp-content/uploads /.../.../`
my new url:

```
https://images.guilaneman.ir/1/
```

i used this code: but it doesnt worked:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/uploads/(.*)$ https://images.guilaneman.ir/1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

note that i have another wordpress blog in subfolder  and i put this code in wp-content folder that I want to redirect.
How can I redirect guilaneman.ir/wp-content/uploads/ to images.guilaneman.ir/1/

Comment: Take a look at : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/77960/103237

Comment: @RaviSachaniya thanks a lot . I read this article but my problem is with redirecting with htaccess.

Comment: @RaviSachaniya  I changed my URLs successfully but I want to redirect the previous path to the new one

Answer (score 0):

Bad matching path on the left side of the rewrite (/uploads/* <> wp-content/uploads/*)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-content\/uploads\/(.*)$ https://images.guilaneman.ir/1/$1 [R=301,L]
```